# Access blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I am using the following versions

> - Python 3.9.6
> - Django 3.2.3
> - django-cors-headers==3.7.0

I have the following in my settings.py

> `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True`
>
> `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http://localhost:3000',)`

For some reason, one of the API call fails out with this error.

> Access to fetch at  from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access->Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves >your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am not able to understand why I get this error.

Here are the relevant request and response details as extracted from Google Chrome Developer tools

**General**
Request URL: http://10.0.123.123:8998/api/box?unit=101&box=TOT000000000051345&login_user_id=USERID&reserve_locn=101

Request Method: OPTIONS

Status Code: 200 OK

Remote Address: 10.0.123.123:8998

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Date: Tue, 07 Sep 2021 01:15:10 GMT

Server: nginx/1.20.1

Vary: Origin

**Request Headers**

OPTIONS /api/box?unit=101&box=TOT000000000051345&login_user_id=USERID&reserve_locn=101 HTTP/1.1

Host: 10.0.123.123:8998

Connection: keep-alive

Accept: */*

Access-Control-Request-Method: GET

Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

Origin: http://10.0.123.123:8999

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Referer: http://10.0.123.123:8999/

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Comment: have you added cors in middleware and installed apps in django settings?

Comment: Are you sending a credentialed request?

Comment: Although [the documentation of django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/3.8.0/) doesn't mention it, `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` takes precedence over `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` (which is an alias for `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`). This becomes evident if you inspect [the source code](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/main/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#L140). This isn't enough to solve your problem, but at least you don't need both configs.

Answer (score 0):

Every IP address or domain that you uses to make request to django server should be added to the settings.py as following:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http://localhost:3000','http://10.0.123.123:8998')
```

Let me know the result in the comments.

Comment: Tried but that does not help. Also, setting CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS to True is specifically  meant to allow all origins without the need to specify all the origins explicitly.